# How to display unorderd list with pictures and next to every picture to have paragraph?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, frontend

Hello everyone i have a small problem i m trying to do this unordered list and i cant display it corectly.

This is how should it look

[image]

This is the code:

```
<ul>
        <li><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Picture 1"></li>
        <li><img src="images/19.jpg" alt="Picture 2"></li>
        <li><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Picture 3"></li>
        <li><img src="images/19.jpg" alt="Picture 4"></li>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempus mauris vitae blandit dapibus. In at dui gravida, pulvinar justo non, adipiscing risus.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempus mauris vitae blandit dapibus. In at dui gravida, pulvinar justo non, adipiscing risus.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempus mauris vitae blandit dapibus. In at dui gravida, pulvinar justo non, adipiscing risus.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempus mauris vitae blandit dapibus. In at dui gravida, pulvinar justo non, adipiscing risus.</p>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You image isn't showing for "This is how should it look".

Comment: what css have you tried ?

Comment: put `<img>` and `<p>` tags together inside your `<li>`.

Comment: Have a look at this - http://pea.rs/content/slats-thumbnails you'll need to float the img left.

Comment: I have try to float the pictures left but they are two on one line , I need..

Comment: @АлександърА. Have you had a chance to view my answer? I believe it may solve your question.

Comment: It's **[not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#Usage_context)** to put a paragraph inside the <ul> element as a child. Only *zero or more <li> elements, eventually mixed with <ol> and <ul> elements*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it should be laid out: http://jsfiddle.net/GU4L2/3/ If this isn't what you are looking for, let me know and I will edit it so that it fits your needs.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li>
    <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Picture 1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempus mauris vitae blandit dapibus. In at dui gravida, pulvinar justo non, adipiscing risus.</p>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/19.jpg" alt="Picture 2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempus mauris vitae blandit dapibus. In at dui gravida, pulvinar justo non, adipiscing risus.</p>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Picture 3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempus mauris vitae blandit dapibus. In at dui gravida, pulvinar justo non, adipiscing risus.</p>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/19.jpg" alt="Picture 4">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempus mauris vitae blandit dapibus. In at dui gravida, pulvinar justo non, adipiscing risus.</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {list-style-type: none;}

li img {
    float: left;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you were very close. You just need to remember the only things that can go inside your `ul` is a list-item (`li`). You can though, place an image and paragraph inside an `li`.

http://jsfiddle.net/vdecree/VW8N7/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="mycontainer">
    <ul id="mylist">
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="placeholder"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, reque error ceteros ex quo, pro ex saepe albucius. Ex pro libris apeirian, et salutandi deseruisse vim. Sea expetendis necessitatibus te, sea inani possit dissentias ea. Persius eleifend qui in. Mei dolore menandri te, in illud falli eirmod vis, est an aeterno interpretaris.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="placeholder"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, reque error ceteros ex quo, pro ex saepe albucius. Ex pro libris apeirian, et salutandi deseruisse vim. Sea expetendis necessitatibus te, sea inani possit dissentias ea. Persius eleifend qui in. Mei dolore menandri te, in illud falli eirmod vis, est an aeterno interpretaris.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="placeholder"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, reque error ceteros ex quo, pro ex saepe albucius. Ex pro libris apeirian, et salutandi deseruisse vim. Sea expetendis necessitatibus te, sea inani possit dissentias ea. Persius eleifend qui in. Mei dolore menandri te, in illud falli eirmod vis, est an aeterno interpretaris.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="placeholder"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, reque error ceteros ex quo, pro ex saepe albucius. Ex pro libris apeirian, et salutandi deseruisse vim. Sea expetendis necessitatibus te, sea inani possit dissentias ea. Persius eleifend qui in. Mei dolore menandri te, in illud falli eirmod vis, est an aeterno interpretaris.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="placeholder"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, reque error ceteros ex quo, pro ex saepe albucius. Ex pro libris apeirian, et salutandi deseruisse vim. Sea expetendis necessitatibus te, sea inani possit dissentias ea. Persius eleifend qui in. Mei dolore menandri te, in illud falli eirmod vis, est an aeterno interpretaris.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="placeholder"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, reque error ceteros ex quo, pro ex saepe albucius. Ex pro libris apeirian, et salutandi deseruisse vim. Sea expetendis necessitatibus te, sea inani possit dissentias ea. Persius eleifend qui in. Mei dolore menandri te, in illud falli eirmod vis, est an aeterno interpretaris.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mycontainer{
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#mylist li:before,
#mylist li:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
#mylist li:after {
    clear: both;
}
#mylist li {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

#mylist li{
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: none;
}

#mylist li p{
    width: 340px;
    float: left;
}

#mylist li img{
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```